# URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected host component): localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure what is wrong but in the console when running `NewsletterMailer.weekly("username-here@gmail.com").deliver` I get the error `URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected host component): localhost:3000`

I double check my settings and everything seems to be fine. Here's the full output of the error:

```
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:605:in `check_host'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:646:in `host='
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:195:in `initialize'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:141:in `new'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:141:in `build'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:206:in `absolute_url_base'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:192:in `ensure_absolute_url'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:180:in `block in make_image_urls_absolute'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `block in each'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `upto'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `each'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:179:in `make_image_urls_absolute'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:57:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:80:in `block in adjust_html'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:79:in `tap'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/roadie-2.4.3/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:79:in `adjust_html'
... 10 levels...
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run__4195001508967449441__process_action__callbacks'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:503:in `process'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `new'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:66:in `<top (required)>'
```

Development.rb:

```
 config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.eager_load = false

  # Change mail delvery to either :smtp, :sendmail, :file, :test
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'username-here@gmail.com',
    password:             'password-here',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: false  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Zajn's answer did not work then do a search for `localhost:3000`. You may have it set somewhere else. When you find it remove the line and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the port number from the url you're specifying as the default host. The value of the `:host` key should be just the host, not the host and the port number.

Comment: Have you restarted your server since making the configuration change?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server.

Comment: I'm using letter opener and still getting file://users/121/edit in mail and missing host can you please help

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the line `config.roadie.url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }` somewhere in your config, maybe development.rb.
road.url_options requires the port to be specified as a separate key.

Try
`config.roadie.url_options = { host: "localhost", port: 3000 }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, try starting server with this command instead

```
bundle exec rails server -b 127.0.0.1
```